# How can I do an Optional JOIN using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, join

I want to return all rows from `biometrics`, and grab extra data if the JOIN exists. However my current query only returns rows when the userid matches.

How may I fix this so it returns all biometric rows, and extra data from the JOIN if it exists?

```
SELECT b.id as id, g.date
FROM `biometrics` as b
INNER JOIN `users goals` as g ON biometricid = b.id and userid = $user->id
```

Comment: Change `INNER` to `LEFT`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a left outer join:

```
SELECT b.id as id, g.date
FROM `biometrics` as b
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users goals` as g ON biometricid = b.id and userid = $user->id
```

Nice examples of different join types can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins).